# Wordpress Development - get the terms - returns 'array'

Tags: wordpress, loops, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to get the terms of a specific taxonomy to display on a page. The code is located in a page template and when I use 'get_the_terms' the result that shows is 'array'. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 3):

It's corrent. As reported in the codex page for [get_the_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) return an array of terms.
You can then use the array later in your code.

Do

```
<?php
   $terms = get_the_terms();
   print_r($terms)
?>
```

to discover the structure of the terms.

This example prints out the name of the terms that are retrieved by the function.

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
 echo $term->name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off-topic, but just yesterday I answered a [question related to this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8391/using-a-loop-to-display-terms-associated-with-a-post/8394#8394) over on wordpress.stackexchange.com. It uncovered some interesting variations on the theme of "getting taxonomies/terms associated with a post".